# php mysql_select_db parameter 2 not working

Tags: php, mysql-select-db

I have the following code for test, and I just found the 2nd parameter is not actually working.

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "xxxx", "xxxx");
$conn2 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "xxxx", "xxxx");

mysql_select_db("test", $conn1);
mysql_select_db("yangshengfun", $conn2);

if (!$res = mysql_query("select * from proxy_ips limit 1", $conn1)) {
    echo mysql_error($conn1);
}


if (!$res = mysql_query("select * from wp_posts limit 1", $conn2)) {
    echo mysql_error($conn2);
```

The tables in database 'test' and 'yangshengfun' are complately different.
An error occured while I run this code:

`Table 'yangshengfun.proxy_ips' doesn't exist`

Seems when I call mysql_select_db for $conn2, it changes the current db of $conn1 too, any ideas?

Comment: Use mysqli instead of mysql class.

Comment: First `don't use mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` and try using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Use mysqli or PDO for this. mysql is deprecate in PHP 5.5 and will be removed in other versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 $conn1= mysql_connect("host_name", "user_name", "pass_word") or die('not connected'); 
 mysql_select_db("database_name", $conn1);
```

Here the "die($message)" function prints a message if mysql_connect() function can't connect with db.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$conn1 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "xxxx", "xxxx", true);
$conn2 = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1", "xxxx", "xxxx", true);
```

Note : `mysql_*` is deprecated. use `mysqli_*` or `pdo`

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqli instead:

```
<?php

    $conn1 = new mysqli(host, user, password, db);

    $conn2 = new mysqli(host2, user2, password2, db2);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `mysql_connect()` of the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> **If a second call is made to mysql_connect() with the same arguments,
> no new link will be established, but instead, the link identifier of
> the already opened link will be returned.** The new_link parameter
> modifies this behavior and makes mysql_connect() always open a new
> link, even if mysql_connect() was called before with the same
> parameters. In SQL safe mode, this parameter is ignored.

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !